# 2.81 Shadows settings missing Exponent value (among other settings)

Tags: rendering

What's with the 2.81 missing shadows settings on lights? A bunch of helpful parameters got removed? I've seen people saying that supposedly shadows work better now, but in fact, I couldn't get the 2.8 results no matter how I tried messing with the parameters that are left (in both the Render and light settings).

I had a problem with light leaking along contact shadows, which I fixed by increasing the Exponent value in the Contact shadows dropdown of the light's shadow settings. Now this parameter is gone, the contact shadows are back to their old ugly self.

[image: Empty scene in both with a spotlight created. As you can see, several parameters are missing in the 2.81]

Comment: Can you [add an example project](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) where this problem is happening or add instructions on how to create such a scene?

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture to the original post and also: the "problem" is very simply recreated, just add pretty much any light (spotlight in my case) and see for yourself that several parameters are missing compared to 2.8 (see pic above)

Comment: The shadow calculation is changed in 2.81 using another method. Those parameter might not available in current developing process.